# how to show text box in div

Tags: javascript

This is my `index.php` page. Also the form is in my popup box for get the description.

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="store(this); return false">
<p>
    <input type="button" name="prev" onclick="goto(this.form, -1)" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" onclick="goto(this.form, +1)" value="Next" />
</p>

<div>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to see this form correctly</noscript>
</div>

<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Store in database" />
</p>
```

this is my Javascript file `upload.js`.

user selected files are there.-->

var files=new Array();
          function insert(fileslist) 
             {
                files[files.length]=fileslist;

```
            var filenames=(files.valueOf());
```

var max = files.length;
var current = 0;
function goto(form, pos) 
    {

```
current += pos;
form.prev.disabled = current <= 0;
form.next.disabled = current >= max - 1;
var fields = form.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) fields[i].style.display = 'none';

fields[current].style.display = 'block';
form['name' + current].focus();
}
```

function store(form) 
    {

```
var input = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
var data = ''; 
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text')
        data += '&' + input[i].getAttribute('name') + '=' + input[i].value;
}
data = encodeURI('n=' + max + data);
var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xhr.open('POST', 'datainsert.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-length', data.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText != '')
             alert(this.responseText); 
     else {

            form.submit.value = 'Saved!';
            setTimeout(function() { form.submit.value = 'Save to database' }, 500);
        }

    }
}
xhr.send(data);

}






window.onload = function() 
{
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var container = form.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    container.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
        container.innerHTML += '<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;"><legend>Files of ' +(i + 1) + ' / ' + max + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>';
    goto(form, 0);

}
```

The `<div>…</div>` did not show the text boxes. Why?

Comment: first of all put you code into code block with format manner, 2nd what you are exactly want?

Comment: You can't use [`goto`](http://xkcd.com/292/) in JavaScript. Moreover, don't add text to `innerHTML` the way you did; use a temporary string instead and change the `innerHTML` once.

Comment: @Marcel, have a look at his input buttons onclicks - goto must be a defined function: `function goto(form, integer) {...}`. I agree the name is bad and misleading, but I don't think he meant to use it like goto from Basic languages.

Comment: @rochal: Ah, yes, you're right. It's just that that keyword triggers some automata in my brains.

Comment: what error do you get? Are you sure that `max` is properly set *before* `onload` is called?

Answer (score 1):

My gut is telling me that you are passing `max` incorrectly, so it is either a undefined or 0 so loop is never run, OR your selectors are wrong - add IDs to your elements and do it like that:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" onsubmit="store(this); return false">
<p>
    <input type="button" name="prev" onclick="goto(this.form, -1)" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" onclick="goto(this.form, +1)" value="Next" />
</p>

<div id="container">
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to see this form correctly</noscript>
</div>

<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Store in database" />
</p>

window.onload = function() 
{
    var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.innerHTML = '';
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        var ofValue = (i + 1) + ' / ' + max;
        html += '<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;">';
        html += '<legend>Files of ' + ofValue + '</legend>';
        html += '<input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br />';
        html += '<input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>';
    }
    container.innerHTML = html;

    goto(form, 0); //I am assuming this is a valid, defined method
                   //because it is also called from onclicks of Next/Prev buttons
}
```

Comment: only i will show two textbox per each click....in your script totally 4  textbox is showing.....................this is html and js scripts in one page.......but i will show the text box in my popup box....above the code did not work.......

Comment: @SANS: the number of boxes that show up is dependent on `max`, you didn't show how it's declared. Again: are you sure `max` is correctly set before `onload` fires? Moreover, `max` isn't passed as a parameter, but a global variable, which you shouldn't use, it's a bad programming habit.

Comment: i have used the concept to get the description for each file........if the user will select 10 file so per each file allocated two textbox per each click..........so max=(10)no of files(totally)i.....i have completed already......but only the div problems ...........so can u give me any idea idea

Comment: @SANS and how and where did you assign `max`? Can you show us your code (by editing your question)? And remember, ‘u’ is a letter, not ‘you’.

Answer (score 0):

put `id="div1"` in you div tag,
this will behave as identifier for JavaScript in you whole page

```
<div id="dvi1">
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to see this form correctly</noscript>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="store(this); return false">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="prev" onclick="goto(this.form, -1)" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" onclick="goto(this.form, +1)" value="Next" />
    </p>

    <div  id="div1">
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to see this form correctly</noscript>
    </div>


    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Store in database" />
    </p>
</form>



window.onload = function() 
{

    var container = documentgetElementByid("div1");
    container.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
        container.innerHTML += '<fieldset style="width: 250px; height: 80px;"><legend>Files of ' +(i + 1) + ' / ' + max + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>';
    goto(form, 0);

}
```